# Input loses value when duplicated

Tags: jquery, forms, duplicates, append, input-field

I have a template for my form fields and I need these fields to be able to  be duplicated multiple times.

See this as sample case:

```
<a href='#' id="add">Add</a><br /><br />
<div id="box">
    <div id="template">
        <input type="text" name="template"></input>
        <br /><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

The script:

```
var template = document.querySelector('#template');
var index = 1;

$('#template').remove();

$('body').on('click', '#add', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#box').append(template);

    var newInput = $('#box').html().replace(/template/g, 'input-'+index);

    $('#box').html(newInput);

    index++;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bedex78/hkk7rx74/7/

Why is it whenever I **input some value** into the fields, the **value disappears upon adding new one** (ie. after clicking the 'ADD' button)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are replacing all of the HTML when using `$('#box').html(newInput);` - that includes all the inputs and values. Use a combination of `clone` to copy the template and `append` to add to the box without replacing its contents:

```
$('body').on('click', '#add', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var wrapper = $("<div>");
    wrapper.append($(template).clone());

    var newInput = wrapper.html().replace(/template/g, 'input-'+index);

    $('#box').append(newInput);

    index++;
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ohbyshko/)

**Note:** The reason I used `clone` here is so that you can modify the new box properly. You don't have to use `html().replace`, but can use DOM manipulation instead, e.g. `wrapper.find("#template")`

Comment: Just curious, how do you use the **DOM manipulation** method you suggested? And which one is better & more efficient?

Comment: So when you have `wrapper`, you can use `wrapper.prop("id", newId)` and other things like `wrapper.find("input").addClass("input input-new")` etc. This is much more efficient and easier to read than replacing HTML as a string.

Comment: Ah, I see... I guess the initial reason why I resolved to using `.replace()` was that my real scenario contains a form with many fields and the occurrence of the word that I wanted to replace is not limited to the `input` tags only or to an attribute of an element, but also in the text content as well. I didn't want to target each occurrence and thus add more lines of code, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the inputed value isn't stored in the html itself.

A solution to your problem would be this :

```
$('body').on('click', '#add', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var newInput = $(template).html().replace(/template/g, 'input-'+index);

    $('#box').append(newInput);

    index++;
});
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hkk7rx74/8/

Comment: I didn't know you could do the changes directly to the variable. Now I know... Anyway, while this works, I needed to include the template's container as well (ie. `div#template`). @RGraham's cloning method seems to do the trick. Nevertheless, tx for the help!